# RSACryptoServiceProvider returns null in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, rsacryptoserviceprovider

After upgrading my project to .NET Core from .NET Framework, RSACryptoServiceProvider is returning null.

I spent a bit of time googling and have been getting mixed messages to RSACryptoServiceProvider and .NET Core 2.1

```
X509Certificate2 root_Cert = new X509Certificate2(pemFile, pemPassword);
X509Certificate2 sign_Cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxFile, pfxPassword);

RSACryptoServiceProvider sign_PrivKey = sign_Cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
```

The code above returns null in the sign_PrivKey within .NET Core, but works fine in .NET Framework 4.7.1.

Comment: It seems that `sign_Cert.PrivateKey` is not derived from `RSACryptoServiceProvider`

Comment: Set a break point at this line and then watch what exactly is `PrivateKey` at debug time.

Comment: thanks for the comments, like i said this is working fine in 4.7.1 and not working in core 2.1

with a break point i can see the private key 
type of {System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey} and a RSA

Comment: @Potnoodle13 but in core 2.1 is not. In such casting you never can be sure that this will work in other version

Comment: This is still not working in .Net Standards 2.1. Anyone has a solution?